# In theme Twenty Eleven, do the default images rotate randomly?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

In theme Twenty Eleven, do the default images rotate randomly, or with some sequence?

As far as I can see, I think it's random, but there might be some pattern/sequence that I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the header image is picked at random;

see this line in /wp-includes/theme.php line 1476:

`$random_image = array_rand( $headers );`

out of interest: why are you asking, and what difference would it make?

Comment: I'm asking because I'm changing the images and wondered whether my sequence of images would be random or if they could appear in order, kind of like an animation: http://richardclunan.com

Answer (score 1):

Random.

[`get_header_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header_image) uses [`is_random_header_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_random_header_image) to check if you hadn't selected specific image and [`get_random_header_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_random_header_image) to retrieve header if true.

Answer (score 0):

well It Rotates Randomly.
But you can change it with your sequence if you want 
remove random function from header.php and add urs.